# RStudio - no symbol named 'X' in scope

Tags: r, rstudio

Why do I get the yellow triangular warnings in the LHS margin in RStudio when using packages like dplyr?  When I begin to use my current version of RStudio (1.0.136) there are no warnings. Then I start to code, mistype something, and a whole bunch of the yellow triangles appear. Yet if I restart RStudio, I begin again with none.

[image: no symbol named X in scope]

Is there a way to suppress and/or prevent this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are code diagnostics, designed to help you catch errors and fix them. You can turn them off if they are annoying and cumbersome.

Here is a link that discusses these features of the IDE and how to change them:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205753617-Code-Diagnostics

Justin

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Help page; this sentence was particularly helpful:  "Toggle this if your code makes heavy use of non-standard evaluation, and RStudio is unable to produce correct diagnostics for you.".  Because I use a lot of NSE, I think I may turn these warnings off.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to execute that function associated with variable outside explicitely so that one global variable will be generated named "site_os_id".

hist( **AGE**, col = " Dark Grey")

while executing above statement I got error as "No symbol named AGE in scope".
Then I executed this statement   **AGE <- hc$AGE**  and then again same above query works.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the warnings, you can trick RStudio as follows:

```
# Source and define variables to prevent code diagnostic warnings
source("the_other_script.R")

if (FALSE) {
  variable1 <- NULL
  variable2 <- NULL
  # etc.
}
```