# no named symbol warning message in R Studio - What does it mean?

Tags: r, warnings, message

I am using an expression in ggplot2 which is as follows:

```
ggplot(data = ltb1) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = YEAR , y = B_IBI )) +
  facet_wrap(STATION ~ BASIN , nrow = 6)
```

`ltb1` is the data set, `x` and `y` are input variables (`YEAR` and `B_IBI`), `STATION` and `BASIN` are classes for the `facet_wrap`. All of the code works properly but I keep getting warning messages (the little yellow triangles with !) which indicate the following:

```
no named symbol "YEAR" in scope etc.
```

The code seems to work but I would like to know why I am getting the error message. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to answer with without seeing what the data looks like. Can you [edit] your question and include the output from `dput(head(ltb1))`?

Comment: Related/duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44835528?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RStudio - no symbol named 'X' in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835528/rstudio-no-symbol-named-x-in-scope)